# Word Automation: Mailing Labels

Tags: com, vbscript, automation, ms-word, wsh

I'm trying to automate Word 2010 to create mailing labels in VBScript. So far I have the following:

```
Set word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
word.Visible = True
word.Documents.Add
word.MailingLabel.CreateNewDocument "5162"
```

I get the error "Command failed" (800A1066). Outputting word.MailingLabel gives the error, "Object doesn't support this property or method." [MSDN's documentation for MailingLabel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff835169.aspx) indicates that that's the correct usage. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Word itself couldn't generate labels either, I just noticed. It would tell me, "There is a problem with the label information you are trying to use."

The gist of the fix is this:

(1) Rename PAGESIZE in the Office installation folder (to create a backup).
(2) Repair Office using the repair option in Add/Remove Programs.
A new PAGESIZE folder will be created, and Word should be able to generate labels again.

Comment: Hi Eric. It would be great if you posted your comment as an answer. You can even accept your own answer in a little while.

Comment: @Remou: Thanks for the reminder. The wait limit for new users discouraged me from posting an answer instead of a comment initially.

Answer (score 1):

Word itself couldn't generate labels either, I noticed. It would tell me, "There is a problem with the label information you are trying to use."

The gist of the fix is this:

1. Rename PAGESIZE in the Office installation folder (to create a backup).
2. Repair Office using the repair option in Add/Remove Programs.

A new PAGESIZE folder will be created, and Word should be able to generate labels again.